# Adding HTML content to a WPF printed page

Tags: c#, html, wpf, string, printing

I have a c# WPF app that emails a report which is a string containing HTML markup, using ms outlook interoperability I can specify the email message format should be rendered in HTML. So my email is rendered in HTML from a string containing HTML markup. This works fine, my email shows a rendered table from my HTML string.

BUT
I also need to print this report using WPF but when I use the same string containing the HTML markup tags, the printout does not perform the rendering I just get an exact copy of the HTML text. So my print out never displays the table.

Can someone please tell me how I can use WPF to print a string containing HTML tags so that the content is rendered before it is printed out, like in my email example ??

Many thanks in advance

Comment: By "print", do you mean real paper or just "display"?  I think your title probably should be "Displaying HTML content in WPF".

Comment: Hi, I mean on real paper, I don't get the table rendered like I do when I email to outlook

Answer (score 2):

Rendering HTML is not a trivial issue.

You could use a [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) to do that for you, or you could use a [HTML to FlowDocument converter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/05/25/606317.aspx) of sorts, the document then could be displayed in a [`FlowDocumentScrollViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer.aspx). There is no direct support for HTML in WPF.

Comment: Hi H.B Our email and printing service exist in their own service assembly. Will the web browser control still work?

Comment: I don't know, that depends on how you print, if you print WPF controls you should be able to use both of my proposed methods, if you have a more low-level approach which just handles strings as input that won't do.